# Can I use 12AWG for my grounding pigtails of 14AWG?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I can only find 12AWG grounding pigtails at my local hardware store but I wanted the pigtails for the 14AWG wire that I'm running right now.

I assume it shouldn't be an issue because I'm not carrying electricity through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean pigtails for use inside an electrical box, yes using 12AWG is fine. 12 is heavier gauge than 14, so generally wherever you use 14 you can use 12.

But you can also just make your own pigtails using a cut of wire from your roll of 14. It's not necessary to buy pre-cut pigtails. And since you can use 14 gauge you probably should, especially for pigtails where the lighter gauge will be easier to fold and tuck into the box.

Comment: Yes, if you like the little green ground screws, they sell just those.  They sell 12 AWG pigtails because they are the universal donor, they work on 12 or 14 circuits.  It's not an issue that backstabs can't handle 12 AWG, because grounds are not allowed to be backstabbed (nor should you ever use backstabs).

Comment: My only reasoning in wanting to use the pre-maid pigtails was I liked the fact that they were sheathed meaning less exposed wire and I find the green wire easier to see than the bare copper. when I'm working in dark or tight spaces.